# Do we need require and Gemfile at the same time?

Tags: ruby

In a ruby program, there is a separate Gem file, which contains the following definitions:

```
source "https://rubygems.org" 
gem "typhoeus" 
gem "json" 
gem "pg" 
gem "google_drive" , "2.1.11" 
gem "mandrill-api"
```

If I do not want this gem file for some reason, then in ruby script, I need to add require for all the libraries, 
such as:

```
 
require typhoeus
require json
require pg
require google_drive, 2.1.11
require mandrill-api
```

will this work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of the Gemfile can be helpful so that you can insure your code will work by using [bundler](https://bundler.io/) which allows you to run `bundle install` which will install the gems to work with the current version of ruby you will be using for your code. It will also add a `Gemfile.lock` file which is a good idea to commit in your version control to insure you have a working stack where the gems and the ruby version are all compatible.

If you only require the files in your script, there is no guaranteed that the gems are actually installed in the scope of that script's runner.  So by having a `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock` and using bundler, you can have portability for your codebase.

#### Update

As per comment by @engineersmnky , you can specify gem version however with this syntax and it should work so long as those gems are installed.  You would first need to make sure to install the version in your terminal:

```
gem install google_drive -v 2.1.11
```

Then you can do this in your ruby file

```
require 'rubygems' 
gem 'google_drive', '2.1.11'; 
require 'google_drive' 
require 'typhoeus'
require 'json'
require 'pg' 
require 'mandrill-api'
```

Comment: You can however use `rubygems` and the `gem` method without a Gemfile to specify a given version e.g. `require 'rubygems'; gem 'google_drive', '2.1.11'; require 'google_drive'` in this case the version will be maintained due to the patches made to `Kernel` by  `rubygems` [Source](https://github.com/rubygems/rubygems/tree/master/lib/rubygems/core_ext)

Comment: @engineersmnky tried that in irb and got `Gem::MissingSpecVersionError: Gem::MissingSpecVersionError`

Comment: Do you have that gem actually installed? You still need to `gem install xxx` just like you would need to do for require naturally. My point was that you can specify a version using `rubygems`

Comment: @engineersmnky yes I installed the gem before running your code in the console.

Comment: You installed version 2.1.11 correct? If so I am not sure what the issue is and I am away from my computer right now but I actively use this functionality in production processes on a daily basis so I am certain that it works.

Comment: @engineersmnky yeah it works when I specify version with `gem install google_drive -v 2.1.11` thanks, I updated answer.